# (Python) (Blender) How can I take the number of every frame on which there are markers?

Tags: python, blender

Is there a way to take every frame number where there is a marker in the timeline and set it as the starting point for a *noise modifier* r of the f-curve on the selected object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker data can be found in `scene.timeline_markers`

The fcurve data is in `object.animation_data.action.fcurves`

If you wanted to add a noise modifier that lasts 10 frames starting at each marker you could use -

```
import bpy

# data_path='location' with an index=1 is the y location curve
fc = bpy.context.object.animation_data.action.fcurves.find('location', index=1)

for m in bpy.context.scene.timeline_markers:
    nmod = fc.modifiers.new(type='NOISE')
    nmod.strength = 1.5
    nmod.use_restricted_range = True
    nmod.frame_start = m.frame
    nmod.frame_end = m.frame + 10
```

Note that the `fcurves.find()` used here is only available from blender 2.76+, for earlier versions you will need to loop through the fcurves and test the `data_path` to find the one you want.